# UIScrollView перестает скролится при добавлении любого объекта (label, button)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Не могу понять что происходит.

1. Добавляю UIScrollView
2. Создаю свойство во ViewController "@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;"
3. в методе viewDidLoad пишу: scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 800.0f);

Все.
Пока UIScrollView пустой, все отлично работает.
Как только добавляю туда любой объект, он перестает скролить.
Что делать?

Comment: Проблема решена. Проблема была в Constraints.
Отключил Autolayout и все в порядке)

Answer (score 1):

Существует проблема работы autolayout с `UIScrollView`. Если кратко, то она состоит в том, что с включенным autolayout контент скролл вью привязывается к фрейму родителя и перестает скролиться.

[Вот тут](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) подробное объяснение от Apple почему и как это происходит и два примера как с этим бороться.